# Java JNI - native method invoked too late in main()

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI to make my java program working with C libraries but native method is invoked too late.

here's my code:

```
public class QuadcopterClient{
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("MPU6050");
        System.out.println("libMPU6050.so loaded.");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't load MPU6050: " + e.toString());
    }
}

public native void HelloWorld();

public static void main(String argv[]) {

    System.out.println("Trying invoke native method");
    QuadcopterClient qc = new QuadcopterClient();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        qc.HelloWorld();
    }
    System.out.println("Method invoked.");

    Thread.sleep(2500);
}
```

then I run it

`pi@raspberrypi ~/local/quadcopterClient $ java -jar -Djava.library.path=. dist/quad*
libMPU6050.so loaded.
Trying invoke native method
Method invoked.
Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world`

You can see the "Hello world" appears on the ending of program.

QuadcopterClient class is placed in "quadcopterclient" florder:

`pi@raspberrypi ~/local/quadcopterClient/src $ ls
AccGyroModule  ClientServerModule  ControlerModule  MotorsModule  quadcopterclient  SharedLibrary`

Pls why? Thx

Comment: It would be helpful for you to provide more of the missing functions, and simplify your code slightly. Where is `QuadcopterClient.HelloWorld()`? You should strip out the `ControlerModule` creation and replace it with a sleep (so you can still `^C` the code, but you dont need to do all funny network connection stuff in the example.)

Comment: I guess the method is invoked on time, but the string it prints is just buffered, and that buffer is not flushed until the application is terminated. Just try to add a newline `\n` when printing a string - it usually helps to flush output earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`stdout` is buffered. You need to call `fflush(stdout);`, or possibly add a newline to the message so that line-buffering flushes it, if that's in effect.

Comment: Thanks it may help. Prioritly I need to invoked methods on time.

Comment: Your method *is* running at the right time.  You're just not seeing its output until later because of buffering.

Comment: @Jurass It *does* help. You've drawn the wrong conclusion from your observations. Methods are invoked when you call them.